# Neo4j Node Overwrites

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm looking to perform periodic refreshes of node data in my neo4j db. A good example of my needs would be company employees -- where if an employee is terminated, they are removed from the graph completely and new employees are added.

Really, deleting all nodes of this label and ingesting a fresh dataset likely suffices -- but it feels quite ugly. Is there a more elegant solution? My fresh data exists in csv and I want to pull it in daily.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a 'last updated' timestamp on your nodes. Each day, do your update using `MERGE`. If the csv data exists on the database, update the timestamp using the `ON MATCH` clause of `MERGE`. If the csv data doesn't exist `MERGE` will create new nodes (make sure to add a timestamp property of some description). E.g:

```
MERGE (n:Person {<selection_filter>})
  ON CREATE SET <required_properties>, n.lastUpdated = date()
  ON MATCH SET
    n.lastUpdated = date()
```

After updating the graph with csv data, run a query which deletes all nodes whose timestamps are before today's; i.e. haven't been updated.
You might find creating an index on lastUpdated will improve performance for the delete query.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file is all active employees, then you can do something like this:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)
SET e.ActiveToday = False
```

```
LOAD CSV FROM "employees.csv" as line
MERGE (e:Employee {employeeID:line.employeeID})
SET e.ActiveToday = True
```

```
MATCH (e:Employee {ActiveToday: False})
DETACH DELETE e
```

The MERGE will create nodes for new employees in the file and match  those that already exist. Both creates and matches will have their ActiveToday property updated. From there, you just match those where the property is still false and remove them.